# Remove crossdomain file from ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crossdomain.xml

I have Asp.Net MVC application and I want to forbid load any resources from this application by clients such as Adobe Flash Player.
Is it safe to remove crossdomain.xml from Asp.net web application what will it effects?

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer on my question. So in case clients would try to load any resources from server if crossdomain.xml is not present it'll throws Rejected error "Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found". So in this case any clients won't be able to works with this server.